# Rails 3.2 - Validate in Model Based on Another Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an AWARD model - there are two forms to create an AWARD. One is for nominating EMPLOYEES, the other is for Non-Employees. The EMPLOYEE form pulls a list of active employees to populate the Nominee selection box. The Non-Employee form has only text fields to populate the Nominee field (because I have no source to populate a selection list).

To dummy-proof the app, I want to run a validation that disallows Employees from nominating themselves (because they will inevitably try to do so!). There is a hidden field on each form to set whether the form is Employee or Non: `<%= f.hidden_field :employee, :value => true/false %>`

So, on the Non-Employee form, if the user types in his own nominee_username, it should throw an error that says he cannot nominate himself.

**I have a validation, but the error throws even if the nominee_username DOES NOT match the nominator.  So, there is a problem with my validation.**

Here's what I've attempted:

```
class Award < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :nominator, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
  belongs_to :nominee, :class_name => 'Employee', :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'

  validate :cant_nominate_self_non_employee_form,
                                :on => :create, :unless => :employee_nomination?


  def employee_nomination?
   self.employee == true
  end

##### the validation below is not working properly - it throws error every time ####
##### only if Employee.username is equal to award.nominee_username, it should error ####

def cant_nominate_self_non_employee_form
  if Employee.where(:username => nominee_username)
    errors.add(:nominator, "can't nominate yourself")
  end
end

end
```

There is an association between the Award and Employee models:

```
 class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :awards, :foreign_key => 'nominator_id'
      has_many :awards, :foreign_key => 'nominee_id'
  end
```

Comment: ruby is not python, you have to check for `Employee.where(:username => nominee_username).exists?`

Comment: But won't that just tell me if the nominator is an Employee, not whether the nominator is the nominee, too? .. I need to check whether Employee.username equals Award.nominee_username.

Comment: Ah, my bad - that does work.  Thank you so much.  If you answer the question, I'll green check ya.  Thanks again.